# VBA Constants List as Arguments and Assignment Statements

Tags: vba, class, parameters, arguments, constants

Is there a way in VBA to create classes and/or methods that have a limited list of acceptable constants to use as arguments or in assignment statements?

These exist already in VBA per the images below:

[image: VBA_Assignment_List]

[image: VBA_Arguments_List]

I would like to incorporate this in my classes.

Comment: You can create an `Enum`  See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) answered my question in his comment.  Thanks Tim!

> You can create an Enum See: cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not a limited set of constants. You type `xlsheethidden` the program sees 0. The compiler puts 0 into the program. Nothing stops you doing this. `ReportCS1.Visible = 1,000,000`. It's an aid to writing programs, it doesn't form part of the finished program.

If you want to limit what can be passed then you'll need to write code checking what was passed, if wrong do `err.raise(&h80070000 OR 13, blah,blah, blah)`.

This turns a WinError into a HResult - 13 seems resonable. = 0x8007000d

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_DATA
//
// MessageText:
//
// The data is invalid.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_DATA               13L
```